# I cant connect to MQTT over Kubernetes (K3s on RPI Cluster)

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt, mosquitto, k3s

Hey guys so ive hit a bit of a snag. I was able to successfully run my yaml files and get containers running for MQTT. The problem is when I try to connect to it, it just doesnt work. So here are my YAML Files

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mqtt
  name: mqtt
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: mqtt
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mqtt
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: eclipse-mosquitto
          name: mqtt
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1883
            - containerPort: 9001
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mosquitto-config-file
              mountPath: /mosquitto/config
            - name: mosquitto-pwfile
              mountPath: /mosquitto/config/pwfile
            - name: mqtt-data-pvc
              mountPath: /mosquitto/data
            - name: mqtt-log-pvc
              mountPath: /mosquitto/log
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: mosquitto-config-file
          configMap:
            name: mosquitto-config
        - name: mosquitto-pwfile
          secret:
            secretName: mosquitto-pwfile
        - name: mqtt-data-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mqtt-data-pvc
        - name: mqtt-log-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mqtt-log-pvc
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "1883"
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
    - name: "9001"
      port: 9001
      targetPort: 9001
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mqtt
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-config
  namespace: mqtt
data:
  mosquitto.conf: |

    persistence true
    persistence_location /mosquitto/data
    log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

    listener 1883
    protocol mqtt

    listener 9001
    protocol websockets 

    allow_anonymous false
    password_file /mosquitto/config/pwfile/pwfile
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-pwfile
  namespace: mqtt
type: Opaque
data:
  pwfile: |
    <BASE64 USERNAME:PW>
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-data-pv
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-path
  local:
    path: /home/pi/Software/mqtt/storage/mosquitto/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - masternode
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mqtt-data-pvc
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-log-pv
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-path
  local:
    path: /home/pi/Software/mqtt/storage/mosquitto/log
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - masternode
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mqtt-log-pvc
  namespace: mqtt
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mqtt-ingress
  namespace: mqtt
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mqtt.local
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: mqtt
              port: 
                number: 1883
```

When I check if my containers are running they are running fine. When I check the logs it shows the following

```
1618785757: mosquitto version 2.0.10 starting
1618785757: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1618785757: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1618785757: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1618785757: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1618785757: mosquitto version 2.0.10 running
```

I try to connect on mqtt.local (as per the ingress) on port 1883 and the logs dont update and it just says connecting using my iPad app

If I go to mqtt.local on my browser the logs do update (I believe they are using websockets)
and it shows the following

```
1618786368: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
1618786368: New connection from 10.42.1.3:48912 on port 1883.
1618786368: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
1618786368: New connection from 10.42.1.3:57298 on port 1883.
1618786368: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

I'll be honest. I'm pretty stumped. Confirmed the username and password a dozen times. Open to ideas if anybody has some to share. Thanks in advance

Comment: If your browser is connecting via websockets (the only real option) then I'd expect to see the connection come in on port 9001 (the websocket port going by your log) rather than 1883 (generally used for unencrypted standard MQTT. I'd suggest you start with (`mosquitto_sub`)[https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html] (or, for websockets, something like the [hive test client](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/) and ensure its working before testing your own client (eliminates your code as a possible cause).

Comment: So a couple of things here 1) you don't have bridging configured for your Mosquitto containers, so replicas=2 will create instances where a packet is published on one container, but the subscriber is connected to the other broker, and thus won't receive it.  Start with replicas=1.  2) Browers only work with WebSockets, and port 1883 is not WebSockets...port 9001 is with your config.  IF you try to connect with WS to port 1883, you will get the errors you are seeing.  3) do a `kubectl get svc` and see what the ''ExternalIP'' is and make sure you are using that on your clients.

Comment: IF you have no ''ExternalIP'', then you need to be sure and define it.  4) What is the error you are seeing on your client(s)?

Comment: thanks for all the comments,  @JD Allen Im actually just trying to connect to the cluster via 1883 using an mqtt client. Do I need an externalIP if I'm using ingress? The error i see is connection refused. Also same issue if i use replicas=1

Comment: thanks for the comment  @Brits. Since this is on my local network im ok to use unencrypted standard. hive test client is in the public domain, I've tried sub from one of the cluster nodes and it doesn't connect. Says connection refused

Comment: @SKS81 I think you misunderstood my point; you said "mqtt.local on my browser the logs do update" but the logs showed a connection on port 1883 (whereas a browser can ONLY use websockets i.e. port 9001 from logs in your question; I suspect you have the wrong port number configured in your webapp). If you are testing with a tool then please update your question with full details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Ingress declaration points to port 1883 which is running native MQTT over TCP.

Ingress sets up a HTTP reverse proxy that points to the service, since MQTT is not HTTP this just won't work.

As pointed out in the comments one option is to change the Ingress to point to port 9001 which is your WebSocket Listener on the broker

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mqtt-ingress
  namespace: mqtt
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mqtt.local
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: mqtt
              port: 
                number: 9001
```

You will then be able to connect with any MQTT clients that support MQTT over Websockets as that protocol is bootstrapped via HTTP.

It's also worth pointing out that the Ingress reverse proxy will be exposing this route on port 80.

The only other way to connect is to connect directly to the cluster node that is running the MQTT broker. But this will mean changing the [ServiceType](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) to NodePort or LoadBalancer and mapping an external IP address.

Comment: Thanks so much. I see what you’re saying now and kicking myself in the backside for not thinking of that logic. It works. Thank you very much to everybody

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the above post, and I guess the problem is the sequence of the "apply" - if the kubectl apply is made using the above yaml file, then the deployment is loaded first and configMap(s) later.  The configMap must be loaded first so that the deployment component could use them.

Comment: Read the accepted answer, this has nothing to do with the order things are deployed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I used "UDP" as a protocol in my Service - mosquitto supports only 1883/TCP. The OP didn't specify the protocol so TCP is used by default.

UPD: mosquitto doesn't support 1883/UDP as was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: MQTT does not run over UDP (quote from [v5 spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901233) "Connectionless network transports such as User Datagram Protocol (UDP) are not suitable on their own because they might lose or reorder data.").

Comment: When I was looking about 1883 , I found many pages similar to the following https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=mqtt according to which 1883 can be UDP and TCP. There were also a few other references about MQTT/UDP implementations. However, mosquitto doesn't seem to support udp which is up to the spec you referenced, so you're correct. Thanks!

Comment: @aderesh MQTT can NOT run over UDP, MQTT-SN can but they are totally different protocols